# Breaking the duplicate chain(s)

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I came searching for differences in quoting and not quoting properties of javascript objects in google ("javascript object quotes property"), for which the top answer is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192517/javascript-object-property-quotes), providing an adequate answer to the question.

However, as that one is marked as a duplicate, I went to the duplicate target, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986182/is-there-any-functional-difference-between-using-and-not-using-quotes-with-javas), and read through that. That's also a duplicate, leading to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534404/in-javascript-what-is-the-difference-between-a-property-name-in-double-quotes), which, like you guessed, is also a duplicate leading to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes), which also has a 'possible duplicate' comment...

How should these duplicate chains be handled? I don't think it's necessary to read through or to have the entire chain of threads, especially as in some cases like this answers are quite similar. The preferred approach is probably to have a canonical question on the issue and as a rule point to that, but how should I as a user facilitate that? Assuming there already is a canonical for this one, is there a way for me to vote to change duplicate targets to point to that one?

Comment: If you have a gold badge in one of the tags you can edit the duplicates

Comment: Not sure why it should be possible to close question as a duplicate of an question which also is closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Ah, that comment is from the old ages where I didn't have mjölnir superpowers and could vote to close as a circular chain :-) Though I sometimes still sprenkle these kind of "see also here" comments with links to closed questions that have useful answers

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I agree, created a separate [feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352272/we-should-not-allow-chains-of-duplicates-to-be-created) out of that

Comment: I once had a tool to find duplicate connected components in the "duplicate-of" graph by mining the data dumps; back on Math.SE when it was smaller, I found some chains around 5-8 questions deep.  These chains aren't as uncommon as you'd think, for better or for worse.

Comment: I devised [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/695958/find-duplicates-that-have-their-targets-as-duplicates?Month=6&Year=2017) that can find duplicate-of-duplicates. It can link to actual question but it doesn't tell how far the chain goes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't find a link to edit what the dupe target is, but we *could* probably re-open, then close them all as dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes).

Which is how it ideally should be done: All referencing the same canonical.

The reason I can't edit the dupe list is probably because of the age of these questions. They all have the "Possible duplicate" text inserted in the actual post.
However, I'm not sure if I could singlehandedly reopen these, for the same reason.

Comment: I've updated the linked questions. They now all reference the same canonical.

Comment: So in summary, we should ping a gold badge holder if we aren't holding it? Or should we raise a new Meta Post for every case?

Comment: You kind of did a disservice by choosing a canonical post which has an incorrect accepted answer here. It is kind of a mess.

Comment: @TravisJ: So, instead I should select an inferior Q/A pair? That question has the best answer. Sure, it may not be the accepted answer, but nothing a few votes can't clarify.

Comment: "but nothing a few votes can't clarify" didn't we establish that people in average don't read past the first answer?

Comment: @Braiam: tbh, that's their own problem.