# We should not allow chains of duplicates to be created

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

[I raised a question about what should we do about duplicate chains](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352139/breaking-the-duplicate-chains), for which answer was that we should fix them to point to canonical question, and a gold hammer wielder needs to do that. Case in point was fixed. However, a good comment was added to the question:

> Not sure why it should be possible to close question as a duplicate of
>   an question which also is closed as a duplicate. – Christian Gollhardt

and indeed, why should we? Since [don't want to delete duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-good-duplicates), to make them more useful, they should point to questions that aren't themselves duplicates.

This is a feature request to prevent that happening in the future. We should implement a check that a duplicate target should not itself be a duplicate.

Someone might ask how big a problem is this. We got [427 of those in June of 2017](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/695958/find-duplicates-that-have-their-targets-as-duplicates?Month=6&Year=2017), 453 before that. You decide if it's worth the effort. I think it would be. Numbers of such questions are in itself small, but these duplicates-of-duplicates tend to be questions that are asked really often and as such also get a lot of visibility.

Comment: Making someone to track all question closed as duplicate of current one *beofre* closing it as duplicate of canonical one would be pain. Feels like equivalent of "question used as duplicate targets may not be closed as duplicates"...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov but it is a pain only once, when closing, whereas now we put that pain to people reading the questions -> significantly more pain...

Comment: So maybe just remove ability to close as duplicates altogether? I don't think anyone welcomes this functionality (see plenty of threads "why these @#@$ idiots closed my q as duplicate" and "can we please somehow reward closing as duplicates")  - there is negative rewards so far for closing as duplicates and you  propose to make it even harder...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov some people do welcome the feature, see [the thread I linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-good-duplicates). How about if system would automatically find the posting at the end of the chain which is not a duplicate, when closing, so it wouldn't be any harder for either people closing or people reading?

Comment: For the reasons @AlexeiLevenkov provided, I think the end of chain detector would be more reasonable :)

Comment: For some reason, the [Meta.SE version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142238/364344) has been better received.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes (if not a lot of times) the duplicates have answers that are different to the answers on the canonical question, and if one of these answers is a better answer for the to-be-closed question than any of the answers for the canonical it makes sense to close it as a duplicate of the already closed question.

It has happened quite often that I was looking for an answer to a problem that I was facing and I found the solution in only one of several questions that were part of a duplicate chain (and not in the canonical).

So unless we merge all duplicate question and answer chains into one canonical I don't think marking a question as a dupe of another duplicate should be disallowed.

Comment: If there are such cases, shouldn't we try to put those answers into canonicals? if not, I don't see much point in canonicals in the first place.

Comment: @eis Yes, that is exactly was I was getting at with my last sentence. If we merge the useful answers into the canonical (and we would have to do that for every duplicate question), then there would be no reason to close anything as a duplicate of another duplicate.

Comment: merging useful answers (which you now mentioned and which I hinted to) and merging all answers (which you mentioned in the answer) seem different ideas to me. Merging all answers into canonical would produce a lot of noise.

Comment: Instead of merge, maybe we could have on the canoical (and any question which is target of a dupe) a sidebar section *see also* or something like that, which links to each duplicate.

Comment: To me, though, it seems that **most** of the time, chains of duplicates are because people don't bother to look to the end of the chain and find the canonical post.  Or they also happen when the duplicate target itself is marked as duplicate afterwards (and there is no way to see on it that it is a duplicate target).