# Should duplicate questions be linked to the original question or any duplicate question in the chain?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-chains

For example, [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381782/what-are-the-requirements-of-a-question-for-it-to-end-up-on-the-hot-meta-posts-s) question of mine was linked to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296425/what-are-the-limitations-to-see-a-question-in-the-hot-meta-posts) dupe which was linked to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257978/how-are-question-on-meta-added-to-the-community-bulletin) question. The final one was the one which actually answered my question.

In this scenario, should we link the dupe to the original question or just any dupe in the chain, or does it not matter?

Comment: The last question in the chain could be added to the list of duplicate links in your question, but I don’t think it really matters.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352139/breaking-the-duplicate-chains say let's point all to the same... on other hand feature-request to prevent chains was less then successful - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352272/we-should-not-allow-chains-of-duplicates-to-be-created.

Comment: Looks to me like a perfect case of data fragmentation and duplication.  Both answers say the exact same thing.  Ideally we should use one or the other as signposts, but *not* both.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not quite sure if there is a specific rule here, but I have a rule of thumb: flag/vote with the post that provides the clearest answer and avoid distracting information.
In your example, which I initially voted to close, I chose the already closed question, because it points you to the other (canonical?) post, but also contains an answer which might be helpful as well. So, I thought that the additional answer helps to provide additional insight.

There can also be the case, where someone asks about problem A which fails due to problem B. But problem B is hard to discover if you don't have deeper knowledge about the topic. If there is then another question, which asks about A and its answer explains why it is caused by problem B (additionally with the link to the final dupe target about problem B), then I would use that question as kind of a "bridge" or "gateway" and use that as the dupe target.
An example for that is this question: [Validating input using java.util.Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner). Although the linked duplicate might already answer the question I've voted to close, I really like the top voted answer to provide additional information and examples on how to validate user input. So choosing this question provides the best information (in my opinion) in this context.

To sum it up: choose the post which answers the question best (mostly the final dupe target), but feel free to chose an "intermediate question" when it provides additional information or context. And if you have access to the proper moderation tools, like a gold badge, then feel free to add multiple post to the list of duplicate questions.

Comment: **FYI:** I wasn't calling your out, I was genuinely curious regarding the process.

Comment: @Script47 No worries, I didn't interpret it that way. I just added *"which I initially voted to close"* to show that this answer is related to the linked question and to explain my thought process in choosing the dupe target there.